# C# delegate compiler optimisation

Tags: c#, optimization, delegates, jit, anonymous

I have started to use anonymous delegates a lot in C# and I have begun to wonder how efficient the complier or runtime is in removing them from the code that is actually run and I haven't seen this detailed anywhere?

Is it clever enough at all to inline them and collapse recursive uses that could be statically deduced?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a case that you'd like it to optimize?

Comment: I doubt that the *compiler* does anything to remove them. The JITer however, may perform a variety of optimizations, which may include inlining such functions.

Comment: However, I believe the JITer will not inline delegates.

Comment: Well at the most complicated level I was thinking of experimenting with the creation of composite objects through partial functions.

That does seem a bit of shame if it can't do that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the C# compiler will not optimize a lambda expression into inline code.  Anonymous delegates and lambda expressions will always produce a corresponding delegate or an expression tree.  This is covered in section 6.5 of the C# language spec

> An anonymous-method-expression or lambda-expression is classified as an anonymous function (§7.14). The expression does not have a type but can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type

In certain cases the lambda will be cached and not recreated for future use.  But it will not be inlined.

Comment: But does what you quoted actually mean they won't - as it seems to me more conceptionally how they should behave from the users view - not what an optimiser may be able to do behind your back?

Comment: @wb, it does not directly state this but it's a requirement.  To be used an anonymous function must be converted to a delegate.  Delegate's are first class types in .Net and can be overridenn to do anything on invoke.  If the C# compiler inlined a delegate it would potentially bypass a user defined DynamicInvokeImpl which would break behavior hence it cannot inline them.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, no, it isn't.

However, unless you're noticing actual performance issues and have tracked them down in a profiler, you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler will never optimize them. However the .NET JIT compiler might if they're simple enough.